# How to define a function $f(x)$ such that $f(1.5)=1.5$, $f(1.)=1$, $f(0.)=0$, etc.?

Tags: function-construction

How to define a function $f(x)$ such that $f(1.5)=1.5$, $f(1.)=1$, $f(0.)=0$, etc.? Namely, if $x$ is an integer with a decimal point, $f(x)$ returns the integer only, otherwise returns $x$.

This will be useful in the labels of the following plots.

```
Table[Block[{a = aa}, Show[Plot[x^a, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLabel -> Style[Row@{"a", "=", aa}, 15]]]], {aa, 0, 2, 0.5}]
```

Comment: I actually just figured out an answer: `f[x_] := If[Abs[FractionalPart[x]] < $MachineEpsilon, IntegerPart[x], x]`

Comment: `f[x_] := If[FractionalPart[x] == 0, IntegerPart[x], x]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are numerous ways to accomplish what you're asking, but here's another way using a single definition:

```
f[x_]:=Piecewise[{{IntegerPart[x],x==IntegerPart[x]},{x,True}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the following definitions (you need both) will do want you're asking:

`f[x_] := IntegerPart[x] /; x == IntegerPart[x]`

`f[x_] := x`